# mysql-shell: assign the return for dba.checkInstanceConfiguration() to a javascript variable

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster, mysql-shell

I am trying to create a javascript file that is invoked by mysql-shell that can automatically

1. test, using `dba.checkInstanceConfiguration("user@mysql-node:3306")`, if instance is ready for cluster devlopment
2. if not invoke dba.configureInstance("user@mysql-node:3306")
3. if instance is ready for cluster development, invoke:

   shell.connect("user@mysql-node:3306")
   cdCluster = dba.createCluster("cd-cluster");
   cdCluster = dba.getCluster("cd-cluster");
   cdCluster.addInstance("user@mysql-node:3306");

When we invoke:

```
dba.checkInstanceConfiguration("user@mysql-node:3306")
```

The resulting text contain either:

```
{
    "status": "ok"
}
```

or something like

```
{
    "config_errors": [
        {
            "action": "server_update", 
            "current": "COMMIT_ORDER", 
            "option": "binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking", 
            "required": "WRITESET"
        }, 
        {
            "action": "server_update+restart", 
            "current": "OFF", 
            "option": "enforce_gtid_consistency", 
            "required": "ON"
        }, 
        {
            "action": "server_update+restart", 
            "current": "OFF", 
            "option": "gtid_mode", 
            "required": "ON"
        }, 
        {
            "action": "server_update+restart", 
            "current": "1", 
            "option": "server_id", 
            "required": "<unique ID>"
        }
    ], 
    "status": "error"
}
```

as part of the response.
Is there a way one can get the json response for use in a javascript function that can be used to dynamically react by either invoking:

```
dba.configureInstance("root@mysql-pri:3306");
```

or

```
cdCluster = dba.createCluster("cd-cluster");
```

The documentation for `dba.checkInstanceConfiguration("user@mysql-node:3306")` suggest, the return is JSON.  When I do:

```
ret =  dba.checkInstanceConfiguration("user@mysql-node:3306")
console.log(ret)
```

..nothing is retured but I can see the text output. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have since discovered my mistake.  Earlier I used:

```
const ret = dba.checkInstanceConfiguration("root@mysql-pri:3306")
console.log('ret:', ret);
```

I have since replaced console.log with print.  I am now able to assign the json return and use it appropriately:

```
print('ret:')
print(ret.status);
```